# Add New Rows Datagridview by linq

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to add new new rows to dataGrid pragmatically.First the code checks to see if the row doesnt already exist, and if not ,it puts new row ; Otherwise it doesn't enter the row in the DatagridView

The problem with my code is that it continuous loops ,adding the same Rows when Events Trigger.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void addJobstoDespatchGrid(DataGridView jobDataGridView)
    {
        using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
        {
            var data = (from a in db.Active where a.Status == "Hold"
                                                 select a);


            foreach (var row in Data)
            {
                if (GridView.RowCount >= 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in GridView.Rows)
                    {

                        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Value);

                        if (row.jobID !=id)
                        {
                            DataGridViewRow rw = new DataGridViewRow();
                            rw.CreateCells(GridView);
                            rw.Cells[0].Value = row.jobID;
                            rw.Cells[1].Value = row.JobType;
                            rw.Cells[2].Value = row.dateTime;
                            rw.Cells[3].Value = row.jobStatus;

                            GridView.Rows.Add(rw);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridViewRow rw = new DataGridViewRow();
                    rw.CreateCells(GridView);
                    rw.Cells[0].Value = row.jobID;
                    rw.Cells[1].Value = row.JobType;
                    rw.Cells[2].Value = row.dateTime;
                    rw.Cells[3].Value = row.jobStatus;


                   GridView.Rows.Add(rw);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually i m using this function with Timer control which is set Intervel is 5 Sec,After every 5 sec it Doubles the same rows

Comment: Are you stopping your timer?

Comment: No, timer should run as well as form is open it is App requiremnt.
i just want code only enter unique data form databse to datagrid view , but my code Duplicate row each time  on timer event

Comment: What your code is supposed to do when a row with same jobId exists the grid? Actually, you are adding a new row for each row in the grid in which JobId is not the given id.

Comment: When a row with same id exist it should not add the row in Data grid.This is all i want @Chris